# Semantic Nested Form for Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this semantic nested form to destroy a nested object in Active Admin.

```
= semantic_form_for book.chapters.new, url: {controller: "admin/products", action: :remove_chapter} do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    li
      label Select
      = f.collection_select :chapter_product_id, book.chapter_products.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: 'Select Chapter'

  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit, label: "Remove Chapter"
```

It works fine, but I feel it is wrong to use a `semantic_for_for book.chapters.new` since I am not actually creating anything.

I am just making a dropdown select based on a collection to remove an Object.

Just looking to see if there is a better way to do this than how I am doing it now.

I was thinking of just adding a delete button in a table_for, but I can't seem to properly direct to the member_action without getting a route error even though I use the exact same route as the controller in the semantic_form (and added `method: :post`).

Tried a whole bunch of options from this thread with no success -- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/53

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of it from a different simpler angle.

I linked to the nested resource's destroy directly, instead of trying to make a member_action in the mother object.

```
table_for product.chapters do
  ...
  column(:delete) { |c| link_to 'Delete', admin_chapter_path(c), class: 'member_link', method: :delete, 'data-confirm': "Are you sure you want to delete this?" }
end
```

And since I wanted to be redirected back to the same page I came from I just hacked into the controller method on the nested Object's page and managed my redirects from there.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Chapter do
  actions :index, :show, :destroy

  controller do
    def destroy
      ...
      redirect_back fallback_location: admin_chapter_path, notice: "Message"
    end
  end
end
```